# Recycler View Showing Only One Item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Ok, so I was recently working on a small project for my own personal preference, and along the way I implemented a small bit of code that did not work. So, as most people would do, I deleted it. But later, I experienced the same glitch that the code prior was causing, but when I checked, it was not there! I may just be plain stupid, blind, or maybe both, but I keep getting only one card in the recyclerView to show up! Feel free to call me stupid if you can find an answer, and I thank you very much in advance.

P.S. Yes, I am very new to Java, so remember this before you decide to roast me.

**My MainActivity:**

```html
package com.example.whateverthefuckyouwant;

//Imports, in case you couldn't tell

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException;

import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.ExponentialBackOff;

import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;

import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.*;

import android.Manifest;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import pub.devrel.easypermissions.AfterPermissionGranted;
import pub.devrel.easypermissions.EasyPermissions;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks {
    GoogleAccountCredential mCredential;
    ProgressDialog mProgress;

    static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1000;
    static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1001;
    static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 1002;
    static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS = 1003;

    private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";
    private static final String[] SCOPES = {SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS_READONLY };

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;


    //ArrayList holding data from the Google Sheets API
    ArrayList<Team> teamAF;
    //Number of cards that the user has cycled through
    int cardNumber = 1;

    //Integers for direction of swipe. 8 = Right, 4 = Left
    int RIGHT = 8;
    int LEFT = 4;

    boolean first = true;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Initialize credentials and service object.
        mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());

        //Create Recycler View
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        //Specific size of Cards
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        //Design choices using LinearLayoutManager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        //Create teamAF array list
        teamAF = new ArrayList<>();
        //Ads another card, so as to make an infinite number of cards
        teamAF.add(new Team());

        //Creating and setting mAdapter with teamAF
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(teamAF);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        //Swipe code for cardView
        ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            //Don't know what onMove does
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "on Move", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }

            // Direction 4 = left, Direction 8 = right
            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
               //Prints swipeDir integer into console
                Log.e(".", swipeDir + "");
                //Sets variables to null, so they can be reset later
                Team t = null;
                //String s is reset to a string of code that enables it to check the string in the API with your answer.
                String s = "";

                //Code for answer. swipeDir == Left(4); Right(8).
                if (swipeDir == LEFT) {
                    //Sets s
                    s = ((TextView) viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.left)).getText().toString();
                } else if (swipeDir == RIGHT) {
                    //checks the answer swiped with he API
                    s = ((TextView) viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.right)).getText().toString();

                }

                //Removes card from array
                t = teamAF.remove(mRecyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(viewHolder.itemView));
                //Adds some nice animation effect
                mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(mRecyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(viewHolder.itemView));

                //Sends a toast message saying "correct" or "incorrect"
                if(t.checkAnswer(s)) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Incorrect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                if(first) {
                    //This make the recyclerView shuffle
                    Collections.shuffle(teamAF, new Random());
                    first = false;
                }

                //Adding one, so the cards can go on forever
                cardNumber++;

                //Calls the methods
                mAdapter = new MyAdapter(teamAF);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                //This is a 'benchmark' type 'achievement'
                if (cardNumber == 50) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Reached 50 Points Without Losing! You're Doing Great!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (cardNumber == 100) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Reached 100 Points Without Losing! You're A Genius!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

        };

        //Allows the swiping inside the recyclerView
        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);

        //Calls the google API
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgress.setMessage("Loading...");
        getResultsFromApi();
    }



    //The green was commented from the site

    /**
     * Attempt to call the API, after verifying that all the preconditions are
     * satisfied. The preconditions are: Google Play Services installed, an
     * account was selected and the device currently has online access. If any
     * of the preconditions are not satisfied, the app will prompt the user as
     * appropriate.
     */
    private void getResultsFromApi() {

        if (! isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            acquireGooglePlayServices();
        } else if (mCredential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
            chooseAccount();
        } else if (! isDeviceOnline()) {
            System.out.println("No network connection available.");
        } else {
            new MakeRequestTask(mCredential).execute();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Attempts to set the account used with the API credentials. If an account
     * name was previously saved it will use that one; otherwise an account
     * picker dialog will be shown to the user. Note that the setting the
     * account to use with the credentials object requires the app to have the
     * GET_ACCOUNTS permission, which is requested here if it is not already
     * present. The AfterPermissionGranted annotation indicates that this
     * function will be rerun automatically whenever the GET_ACCOUNTS permission
     * is granted.
     */
    @AfterPermissionGranted(REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS)
    private void chooseAccount() {
        if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(
                this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)) {
            String accountName = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null);
            if (accountName != null) {
                mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                getResultsFromApi();
            } else {
                // Start a dialog from which the user can choose an account
                startActivityForResult(
                        mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(),
                        REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
            }
        } else {
            // Request the GET_ACCOUNTS permission via a user dialog
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    "This app needs to access your Google account (via Contacts).",
                    REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS,
                    Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when an activity launched here (specifically, AccountPicker
     * and authorization) exits, giving you the requestCode you started it with,
     * the resultCode it returned, and any additional data from it.
     * @param requestCode code indicating which activity result is incoming.
     * @param resultCode code indicating the result of the incoming
     *     activity result.
     * @param data Intent (containing result data) returned by incoming
     *     activity result.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(
            int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch(requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES:
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

                } else {
                    getResultsFromApi();
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null &&
                        data.getExtras() != null) {
                    String accountName =
                            data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                    if (accountName != null) {
                        SharedPreferences settings =
                                getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                        editor.apply();
                        mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                        getResultsFromApi();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    getResultsFromApi();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Respond to requests for permissions at runtime for API 23 and above.
     * @param requestCode The request code passed in
     *     requestPermissions(android.app.Activity, String, int, String[])
     * @param permissions The requested permissions. Never null.
     * @param grantResults The grant results for the corresponding permissions
     *     which is either PERMISSION_GRANTED or PERMISSION_DENIED. Never null.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(
                requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
    }

    /**
     * Callback for when a permission is granted using the EasyPermissions
     * library.
     * @param requestCode The request code associated with the requested
     *         permission
     * @param list The requested permission list. Never null.
     */
    @Override
    public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, List<String> list) {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    /**
     * Callback for when a permission is denied using the EasyPermissions
     * library.
     * @param requestCode The request code associated with the requested
     *         permission
     * @param list The requested permission list. Never null.
     */
    @Override
    public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, List<String> list) {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the device currently has a network connection.
     * @return true if the device has a network connection, false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean isDeviceOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr =
                (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
    }

    /**
     * Check that Google Play services APK is installed and up to date.
     * @return true if Google Play Services is available and up to
     *     date on this device; false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability =
                GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        final int connectionStatusCode =
                apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        return connectionStatusCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to resolve a missing, out-of-date, invalid or disabled Google
     * Play Services installation via a user dialog, if possible.
     */
    private void acquireGooglePlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability =
                GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        final int connectionStatusCode =
                apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(connectionStatusCode)) {
            showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Display an error dialog showing that Google Play Services is missing
     * or out of date.
     * @param connectionStatusCode code describing the presence (or lack of)
     *     Google Play Services on this device.
     */
    void showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
            final int connectionStatusCode) {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        Dialog dialog = apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(
                MainActivity.this,
                connectionStatusCode,
                REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
        dialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * An asynchronous task that handles the Google Sheets API call.
     * Placing the API calls in their own task ensures the UI stays responsive.
     */
    private class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
        private com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets mService = null;
        private Exception mLastError = null;

        MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
            HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
            mService = new com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets.Builder(
                    transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("Google Sheets API Android Quickstart")
                    .build();
        }

        /**
         * Background task to call Google Sheets API.
         * @param params no parameters needed for this task.
         */
        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                return getDataFromApi();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                mLastError = e;
                cancel(true);
                return null;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Fetch a list of names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
         * https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
         * @return List of names and majors
         */
        private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
            String spreadsheetId = "1KlflsDsBn0lhGT87OuRuy_RGOuBP2jBU5zpqn_UIYT0";
            String range = "Sheet1!A2:B";
            List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
            ValueRange response = this.mService.spreadsheets().values()
                    .get(spreadsheetId, range)
                    .execute();
            List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
            for (List row : values) {
                //Obtains the row from the Google Sheet
                teamAF.add(new Team(row.get(0).toString(), row.get(1).toString()));
            }
            //Shuffle the cards with the data on them.
            Collections.shuffle(teamAF, new Random());

            /*for(String s : results) {
                Log.e("HERE", s);
            }*/

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //mOutputText.setText("");
            mProgress.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> output) {
            mProgress.hide();
            if (output == null || output.size() == 0) {
                //mOutputText.setText("No results returned.");
            } else {
                output.add(0, "Data retrieved using the Google Sheets API:");
                //mOutputText.setText(TextUtils.join("\n", output));
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mProgress.hide();
            if (mLastError != null) {
                if (mLastError instanceof GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) {
                    showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
                            ((GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) mLastError)
                                    .getConnectionStatusCode());
                } else if (mLastError instanceof UserRecoverableAuthIOException) {
                    startActivityForResult(
                            ((UserRecoverableAuthIOException) mLastError).getIntent(),
                            MainActivity.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                } else {
                    //mOutputText.setText("The following error occurred:\n"
                            //+ mLastError.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                //mOutputText.setText("Request cancelled.");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**My Adapter:**

```html
package com.example.whateverthefuckyouwant;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by ebuttikofer20 on 1/20/17.
 */

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Team> mDataset;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView mTextView;
        public TextView left;
        public TextView right;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
            left = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.left);
            right = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.right);

        }
    }


    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Team> myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }
    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;

    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your data at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element

        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset.get(position).getTeamName());
        Random gen = new Random();

        if(gen.nextBoolean()) {
            lefter = mDataset.get(position).getTeamNumber();
            righter = mDataset.get(gen.nextInt(mDataset.size())).getTeamNumber();
            holder.left.setText(lefter);
            holder.right.setText(righter);
        } else {
            righter = mDataset.get(
                    position).getTeamNumber();
            lefter = mDataset.get(gen.nextInt(mDataset.size())).getTeamNumber();
            holder.right.setText(righter);
            holder.left.setText(lefter);

        }

    }

    String righter;
    String lefter;

    public String getLeft() {
        return lefter;
    }

    public String getRighter() {
        return righter;
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your my_text_view  code too

Answer (score 0):

set your parent layout's height in your R.layout.my_text_view file to wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge but i had to set my parent layout height to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
That worked for me so well